# How to get list of selected AD Groups, that a large list of users are members of?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have the below working script that checks if a large list of users in a CSV file are a member of an AD group and writes the results to results.csv.

Not sure how to convert the script so I can change `$group = "InfraLite"` to `$group = DC .\List_Of_AD_Groups.CSV`.

So the script doesn't just return matches for one AD group but so it returns matches for the 80 AD groups contained in the List_of_AD_groups.csv also. Writing a YES/NO for each AD group in a new column in the CSV (or if that's not possible creating a seperate .csv file for each group with results would do also.

I could do this manually by changing the value of `$group` and export file name, and re-running the script 80 times but must be a quick was with PS to do this?

e.g. `results.csv`:

```
NAME   AD_GROUP1 AD_GROUP2 AD_GROUP80 etc etc.
user1     yes        no         yes
user2     no         no         yes
user3     no         yes        no
```

```bsh
echo "UserName`InfraLite" >> results.csv

$users = GC .\user_list.csv
$group = "InfraLite"

$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive |
           Select -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName

foreach ($user in $users) {
    if ($members -contains $user) {
        echo "$user $group`tYes" >> results.csv
    } else {
        echo "$user`tNo" >> results.csv
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trivial solution to your problem would be to wrap your existing code in another loop and create an output file for each group:

```
$groups = Get-Content 'C:\groups.txt'

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember ...
    ...
}
```

A more elegant approach would be to create a group mapping template, clone it for each user, and fill the copy with the user's group memberships. Something like this should work:

```
$template = @{}
Get-Content 'C:\groups.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  $template[$_] = $false
}

$groups = @{}
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | ForEach-Object {
  $groups[$_.DistinguishedName] = $_.Name
}

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
  $groupmap = $template.Clone()
  $_.MemberOf |
    ForEach-Object { $groups[$_] } |
    Where-Object { $groupmap.ContainsKey($_) } |
    ForEach-Object { $groupmap[$_] = $true }
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $groupmap
} | Export-Csv 'C:\user_group_mapping.csv' -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

I played with this for a while, and I think I found a way to get you exactly what you were after.

I think [Ansgar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) was on the right path, but I couldn't quite get it to do what you were after.  He mentioned that he didn't access to an AD environment at the time of writing.

Here is what I came up with:

```
$UserArray = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\Users.txt'
$GroupArray = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\Groups.txt'
$OutputFile = 'C:\Temp\Something.csv'

# Setting up a hashtable for later use
$UserHash = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Hashtable

# Outer loop to add users and membership to UserHash
$UserArray | ForEach-Object{
    $UserInfo = Get-ADUser $_ -Properties MemberOf
    # Strips the LPAP syntax to just the SAMAccountName of the group
    $Memberships = $UserInfo.MemberOf | ForEach-Object{
        ($_.Split(',')[0]).replace('CN=','')
    }
    #Adding the User=Membership pair to the Hash
    $UserHash.Add($_,$Memberships)
}

# Outer loop to create an object per user
$Results = $UserArray | ForEach-Object{
    # First create a simple object
    $User = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Name = $_
    }
    # Dynamically add members to the object, based on the $GroupArray
    $GroupArray | ForEach-Object {
        #Checking $UserHash to see if group shows up in user's membership list
        $UserIsMember = $UserHash.($User.Name) -contains $_
        #Adding property to object, and value
        $User | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_ -Value $UserIsMember
    }
    #Returning the object to the variable
    Return $User
}

#Convert the objects to a CSV, then output them
$Results | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $OutputFile
```

Hopefully that all makes sense.  I commented as much of it as I could.  It would be very simple to convert to using ADSI if you didn't have RSAT installed on whatever machine you're running this on.  If you need that let me know, and I'll make some quick modifications.

I've also tossed a slightly modified version of this in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mpearon/a83f8e2920f56228a95bb5f6fdc1eaa6) for later reference.